# How to toggle a hidden ul by clicking a link with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following code created dynamically with php.

What I want to do is when I click class='toggle' with href of desc76, I want to show ul with id desc76.

also I want to change arrowdown16.png to arrowup16.png.

Then when I click it, ul will fadeOut or hidden again.

class, secondul has CSS display:hidden;.

I tried this, but it does not work.

```
 $(".toggle").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = "#"+$(this).attr('href')
     $("id").show("slow");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
...
...
<li class='toggledetail'>
Show Details
<div>
<a href='desc76' class='toggle' >
<img src="http://blablabla.com/assets/icons/arrowdown16.png"  alt="arrowdown16"  title="Show Details" /></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class='secondul' id='desc76'>
<li class='listdetail'>Spec Details<div>0</div>
</li>
</ul>
<li class='toggledetail'>
Show Details<div>
<a href='desc75' class='toggle' >
<img src="blablabla.com/assets/icons/arrowdown16.png"  alt="arrowdown16"  title="Show Details" /></a>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class='secondul' id='desc75'>
<li class='listdetail'>Spec Details<div>0</div>
</li>
</ul>

... Here comes more ul
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated for image:**

```
$(".toggle").live('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = "#"+$(this).attr('href');
    // change image of the next element
    $(this).next('img').attr('src', 'path here');
    $("id").show("slow");
});
```

Note if you want to show/hide the element with click on the same element, you need to use `slideToggle` instead of `show`. Or you can use the `animate` method with `opacity:'toggle'` for fadding toggle effect.

You need to use [`live()`](http://jquery.com/live) method for dynamically generated elements:

```
$(".toggle").live('click', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = "#"+$(this).attr('href');
    $("id").show("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my post. I actually want to toggle to show and hide and change image. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i dont think he means that kind of dynamically like AJAX. he just means the content is made with PHP. not a static HTML page. live wont help.

Comment: +1 for a brave attempt at decrypting the question with a workable solution =)

Comment: Yes, content is created by php not ajax.

Comment: @Stefanvds: Either way, the `live` will work. I just posted just in case :)

Comment: I added event in .live('click', function(event) to work. However it still does not display. It could be with html/css?

Comment: $("id").show("slow"); should be $(id).show("slow");then it works.